# how to duplicate a text message ina label via a button click in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, button, label

I am not sure if this question has been asked but I could not find it. This is my first week to study VB.NET and I am supposed to create program that does several things which I have done but I am stuck on something I cannot help but feel is so simple yet I cannot find the solution to. I need to click a button that is supposed to display a message in a label which it does but successive clicks are supposed to keep duplicating same line in the label which I cannot get it to do. I have not seen anything similar on Youtube, Lynda, my text or anywhere else. Can someone help me or at least point me in the right direction. By the way, I am using Windows Forms Applications if it makes any difference.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the code you're working on?

Comment: Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I got you right.

Try this:

If Button Clicked

```
Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "New Text" 'This will always keep the current Label - Text in the beginning
Label1.Text = "New Text" 'This will only keep the string "New Text" in the Label :-)
```

Have a nice day!